OneSignal 403 Access Denied
I'm trying to send a notification using OneSignal, but running into the following error.
{"errors":["Access denied.  Please include an 'Authorization: ...' header with a valid API key (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys)."]}%        

I doubled and tripled checked that the key I'm using is from Account & APIKey -> User Auth Key.
This is my typescript call
  const response = await fetch('https://api.onesignal.com/notifications', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Basic <<removed>>',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      app_id: "<<removed>>", 
      contents: { en: data.report_title },
      include_player_ids: "Subscribed Users",
      headings: { en: 'New Notification' }, 
    }),
  })


Chatted with OneSignal and they recently changed the API to use REST Api key instead of User Auth Key.
